# Copy/paste full command line in a terminal but discard the prompt section

Tags: fish

Is there a way in fish to copy/paste the full command line in a terminal that includes a function, paste it but exclude the prompt part?

Meaning, if I executed an ls like this:

```
fish_prompt> ls
```

I want a way that when copying the full line and pasting it, the prompt section is ignored:

```
fish_prompt> fist_prompt> ls
```

So I want the above line to be handled as if I just copied the ls part only.

This is achieved in bash shells for example by having : and ; part of the prompt like this:

```
: bash_prompt> ;
```

So now copy paste that, what ever inside the : ; is considered a comment and wont be executed. Is there a comparable thing in fish?

Comment: I don’t know whether such a function exists builtin to [**Fish**](https://fishshell.com), but if not, you could make one yourself.  The Fish prompt is, itself, a function, the output of which could be used as a substring to be removed from the beginning of the command-line copy/paste result.

Comment: Intersting thought

Comment: `function :; end`

Comment: glenn I am not sure what that does. Are you trying to replicate how bash does it's commenting?

Comment: Also, note that `:` is not a comment. It still expands command substitutions, so there can be side-effects. `: $(rm /some/important/file)` will delete that important file.

Comment: That fish function replicates bash's `:` command.

Comment: You are right!!! it worked

Comment: Your bash example doesn't work because the `>` redirection is still processed and since nothing follows it you get an "unexpected token" error. You cannot do this safely in bash or fish unless you can guarantee the prompt will not contain anything (like a `>` redirection) which has side-effects. With that caveat I would do it using glenn's solution.